# VS Studio 2019 error when trying to publish self-contained

Tags: c#, linux, visual-studio, .net-core, publish

I wrote a c# console application that I want to compile for a linux machine. When I use the following command in the console, I get this error:

```
dotnet publish -r linux-x64 --self-contained true

C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.300\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3983,5): error MSB4062: The "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ResolveManifestFiles" task could not be loaded from the assembly Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core, Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a.  Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask. [X:\Coding\Visual Studio 2019\Projects\firstDiscordBot\firstDiscordBot\firstDiscordBot.csproj]
```

I read through a lot of similar questions but none of the solutions worked for me. I tried deleting the .vs folder inside my solution's project folder and did Clean and Build and I tried entering `Install-Package MSBuildTasks` into the NuGet Package Manager Console and then rebuilding my project.

(Error message in plain text, maybe a bit easier to read:)

C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.300\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3983,5): error MSB4062: The "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ResolveManifestFiles" task could not be loaded from the assembly Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core, Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a.  Confirm that the  declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask. [X:\Coding\Visual Studio 2019\Projects\firstDiscordBot\firstDiscordBot\firstDiscordBot.csproj]

[Edit]
I did some experiments and now the error message says the following:

C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.300\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3975,5): error MSB4062: The "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.SignFile" task could not be loaded from the assembly Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core, Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a.  Confirm that the  declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask. [X:\Coding\Visual Studio 2019\Projects\firstDiscordBot\firstDiscordBot\firstDiscordBot.csproj]

I guess the error is basically the same, it probably won't matter much.

I also did some more research and I tried several more things, such as using the 'Publish' feature when right-clicking my project in the Solution-Explorer and reinstalling the SDK. I also verified all my files several times but none of the above helped.

I just want to mention that every little suggestion would be greatly appreciated as this is the first time, that I don't seem to able to fix the problem, even after multiple hours of research and dedication. So if there's anything you think I could do, I would be very happy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone with the same issue, I fixed it. My problem was simply that I was using a .NET-Framework project instead of .NET-Core. Watch out on that.

Comment: @Time Kluge what is the way to tell that our project is .NET-Framework vs. .NET-Core? In my project properties, Target framework is set to .NET 6.0. Does that mean it is impossible to set the project as self-contained?